# Ember - async computed property or observer?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, promise

So I'm new to Ember and trying to work out the best way to set a computed property that depends upon related model data. I'll include the models below FYI.

I want to set the computed property to an asynchronous result (desiredOutcome). 
**My question** is how do I this? Or is it more appropriate to use an observer, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569986/ember-async-computed-property-returns-undefined).

```
score: function() {
    var self = this;
    var allscores = this.get('model.scores');

    //Find the scoreRecord that has the appropriate objective id (in this case just 1)
    var scoreRecord = allscores.find(function(item){
        var scoreID = item.get('id');

        return self.store.find('score', scoreID).then(function(scoreRecord){
            var objID = Number(scoreRecord.get('objective.id'));
            if (objID === 1){return true;}
        });
    });

    //Return the scoreRecord's score attribute
    var scoreID = scoreRecord.get('id');
    return this.store.find('score', scoreID).then(function(score){
        var desiredOutcome = score.get('score');
        console.log(desiredOutcome);
        return desiredOutcome;
    });
}.property('model.@each.scores', 'selectedObjective'),
```

Apologies for the poor choice of variable names etc...

My models:

**student**

```
scores:   DS.hasMany('score', {async: true}),  
name:     DS.attr('string')
```

**objective**

```
name:     DS.attr('string'),
scores:   DS.hasMany('score', {async : true})
```

**score**

```
scoreResult:  DS.attr('number'),
objective:    DS.belongsTo('objective', {async: true}),
student:      DS.belongsTo('student', {async: true})
```

-------------**Update**---------------

JSBin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/caxomo/3/edit?js,output). So what I'd like is to return one of the scores, the 1 or 2 that are being logged in the console, as the computed property "score". But I'm assuming I'm just returning an unresolved promise - Inexperienced with promises - How do I adapt so that it resolves?

--I've also been thinking it might be better for me take a different approach with what I'm trying to do here. I might look into creating a component with a model of the appropriate "score". I'll update with some details if that works out.

Comment: can you throw this into a ember.jsbin.com?

Comment: should that be `model.scores.@each` instead of `model.@each.scores`?

Comment: Added to JSBin, but I've broken it! Stopped working when I started putting in fixture data. I've only been using Ember-CLI, can I use DS.FixtureAdapter in JSBin?

Comment: yes, but you need to add ember-data.js http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wafisa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out at all?

Comment: Can you duplicate the issue in the jsbin in my comment and then I can try to take a look?

Comment: Just updated above. Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: What does `allscores.find()` return? The other two finds return promises.

Answer (score 4):

As i struggled with the same thing today, it appears the answer is to use **`DS.PromiseObject`**  .

So first you include it with:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
```

then you create your computed property like:

```
property: Ember.computed('id', function(){
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({
        promise: this.get('store').findRecord('account', this.get('id')).then((data) => {
            return 'Mr. ' + data.get('name');
        })
    });
})
```

and finally in your template you can access the result with **content** (this is the catch) :

```
{{property.content}}
```

and that is all :) in this particular case when you change the Id it will resolve and display a new Name.

Answer (score 0):

like Kalman said above, you need to look over each of the scores so you need to change your property params to

```
property('model.scores.@each', 'selectedObjective'),
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue I really need help with here is in returning a value that comes from a promise. Or whether an observer could be better used.